# Is this stochastic integral well-defined?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

Let $x_t = \int_{s=0}^t dW_s$ where $W_t$ is the standard Weiner process. Now I define
$$
f(x_t) = \frac{1}{(2-x_t)^4}
$$
Using Ito's Lemma,
$$
df(x_t) = \frac{4}{(2-x_t)^5}dW_t - \frac{10}{(2-x_t)^6}dt.
$$
and
$$
f(x_t) = \int_{0}^{T}\frac{4}{(2-x_t)^5}dW_t - \int_{0}^{T}\frac{10}{(2-x_t)^6}dt.
$$
My main question is if the Ito integral $\int_{t=0}^T \frac{4}{(2-x_t)^5}dW_t$ well-defined or even bounded for $T=1$?

I have tried to show $L^2$ integrability in expectation by using Fubini's Theorem, i.e., proving $\mathbb{E}[g^2(t)] < \infty$ for all $0 <t <1$ and therefore, $\mathbb{E}[\int_{t=0}^T g^2(t)dt] < \infty$.
$$
\mathbb{E}[g^2(t)] = \mathbb{E}\left[\frac{16}{(2-x_t)^{10}}\right] = 16\int_{0}^{\infty} \Pr\left(\frac{1}{(2-x_t)^{10}} \geq r\right)dr \leq 16\int_{0}^{\infty}\Pr\left(1 + r^{-1/10}\geq x_t \geq 2 - r^{-1/10}\right)dr
$$
Let $u = r^{-1/10}$, then
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}\Pr\left(2 - r^{-1/10}\leq x_t \leq 2 + r^{-1/10}\right)dr = 10\int_{0}^{\infty}u^{-11}\Pr\left(2 - u\leq x_t \leq 2 + u\right)du
$$

which I don't think is bounded.
Any suggestions about how to prove this integral is well-defined or bounded would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Let $\tau:=\inf\{t: x_t=2\}$, so that $\lim_{t\uparrow \tau} f(x_t)=+\infty$. Your stochastic integral also runs into trouble at time $\tau$. The quadratic variation of $\int_0^t (2-x_s)^{-5} dW_s$
is
$$
Q_t:=\int_0^t (2-x_s)^{-10} ds,\qquad 0\le t<\tau,
$$
so that $\lim_{t\uparrow\tau}Q_t=+\infty$. In short, the Ito integral $I_t:=\int_0^t (2-x_s)^{-5} dW_s$ is only well-defined on the random interval $[0,\tau)$, and
$$
\limsup_{t\uparrow\tau}I_t=+\infty,\qquad \liminf_{t\uparrow\tau}I_t=-\infty.
$$